# Website not loading after using file manager and GIT control. Using Cpanel and Inmotion hosting

Tags: hosting, cpanel

tried everything to host my website that I made using VS code. Bought the domain from godaddy and using inmotion hosting. Tried using file manager wont work and tried using Git control and that has not worked. Put the folder in public_html put still showing nothing? When I do upload a plain index.html file the page goes from showing inmotion hosting info to a plain image but when I upload my projects index.html nothing shows up?

First time ever uploading a website would love some help been trying this for ages

ried using file manager wont work and tried using Git control and that has not worked. Put the folder in public_html put still showing nothing? When I do upload a plain index.html file the page goes from showing inmotion hosting info to a plain image but when I upload my projects index.html nothing shows up?